# nodejs module depedendencies with different versions

Tags: node.js

I have the following confusion regarding module dependencies in nodejs, lets say you have the following dependency structure
moduleA (dependent on Version 1 of Module C)
moduleB (dependent on Version 2 of Module C)

Now under the normal circumstances when each module has its own sub directory the modules (A and B) can easily identity the sub modules versions appropriately, however if we use something like webpack it generates one single file.  How are the versions handled in such a scenario?

On the same note how does flatten-packages work when it comes to different versions?

Comment: Are you using webPack to generate files that the browser will consume (delivered by node.js)?  Or are you using webPack for actual script files that will run on node.js?  I'm under the impression that webPack is built to package stuff that will be run in the browser, but your question sounds like it's describing things that run in node.js.  That has me confused.

Comment: I'm using webpack for node

Comment: Why do you pack things just run on node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack will include both versions of Module C in the bundle. Modules A and B will use Versions 1 and 2, respectively.